# How do I search for all the places that a field or table are used in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to know all the places where a table / field are used in my SQL Server database.

I'm after all the stored procedures, triggers, functions etc. that do anything with this table / field.

The 'Find' options don't seem to do this and I can't believe that the only way to do this is to write a query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use very old yet free tool from Red Gate. It is called SQL Search. It can search any database object by simply specifying name. And great thing is it is actually SSMS addin so you can just use it from SSMS. I am even using it with SSMS 2012.

P.S. I am not in any way affiliated with Red Gate

Comment: Perfect!!! I'm amazed SQL Server Management Studio doesn't have equivalent functionality.

Comment: This IS my long time wish too. But as long as this tool stays compatible with SQL Server I am OK

Answer (score 6):

A query is the only what I know. I use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%WhateverIAmSearchingFor%'
```

I'll be interested to see if someone posts a better query, perhaps, that I can replace this with. I've had it a long time.

Comment: I think it would be better if the where condition is changed to `m.definition Like '% WhateverIAmSearchingFor %'` **with spaces**

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli Or, `' ' + m.definition + ' ' Like '% WhateverIAmSearchingFor %'` - to match with or without spaces...

Answer (score 2):

Looks into views, functions, triggers, stored procedures, etc:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SO.NAME
  FROM SYSOBJECTS SO INNER JOIN
       SYSCOMMENTS SC ON SC.ID = SO.ID
 WHERE SC.TEXT LIKE '%foo%'
```

Comment: I keep that on a stored procedure called by a keyboard shortcut on SMSS, that's always useful

Comment: Only problem with syscomments as opposed to sql_modules is that syscomments.text is an nvarchar(4000) column and sql_modules.definition is an nvarchar(max). So syscomments can theoretically truncate part of the definition of large objects.